# Where can I find orbital parameters for historical satellites and other spacecraft?

Tags: orbit, history, tiros-spacecraft

Upon reading about the history of the [TIROS satellite series](http://science1.nasa.gov/missions/tiros/) and looking at some of the photographs taken by TIROS-1, I wonder what kind of orbit they were in.  Clearly they were polar or at least with a high inclination, but were they sun-synchronous?

Where can I find such information?

[image: TIROS-1 photograph]

<sup>TIROS-1 photograph, 28 April 1960, 16:00 GMT</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Jonathan McDowell](http://www.planet4589.org/space/jsr/jsr.html) keeps a great launch record, as well as a satellite catalog. If you cannot find something there, you likely will not find it anywhere else online.

TIROS 1 appears to have been in a 690x754 km orbit at 48.4deg inclination (I think... Hard to read on mobile).

Comment: I found the log, but I don't seem to find a key to the different columns.  Would the last four columns be `Period [minutes]`, `Perigee [km]`, `Apogee [km]`, `Inclination [degrees]`?  `LEO` is Low Earth Orbit and `LEO/S` appears to be Sun-Synchronous and `/R` retrograde, but `/I` and `/P`?

Comment: I downloaded the launch log, but there are no orbital parameters.  Where did you find this information?

Comment: Check the satellite catalog as well.

Comment: [Direct link to spacecraft catalogue](http://planet4589.org/space/log/satcat.txt), but I haven't found a key yet, nor an explanation of acronyms.

Comment: @gerrit Not sure about a key, but those acronyms are explained at the bottom of this page: http://planet4589.org/space/log/orbits.html

Comment: And based on the [geostationary orbit catalog key](http://planet4589.org/space/book/LOGS/logindex/geo.html) I think you're right; it's `Orbital Period (minutes)`   `Perigee (km) x Apogee (km) x Inclination (degrees)`

Comment: @JeffBurka Thanks.  That leaves the acronyms for the agencies, though: RVSN, OKB1, OSCAR, BNC, PVO, ATT...

Comment: Is that maybe covered in [this gigantic list](http://planet4589.org/space/lvdb/sdb/Orgs)? I think it's the name of the organization that designed or built each satellite? For instance, the most recent entry in the satellite log has CASC in that column, and this orgs list tells us that stands for "China Aerospace Sci/Tech Corp".

Comment: @JeffBurka - Great finds, thanks! Yes, that list covers all of them that I've searched through, for example `PVO` means "Proto-Vozdhusnoy Oborony" or "Air Defense (USSR Armed Forces)".

Answer (score 2):

[Space-Track.org](https://www.space-track.org) is another great source for historical satellite orbit data. Free, but email registration is required.